# Apache "Module mod_alias does not exist"

Tags: debian, apache-httpd

I installed apache on Debian:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 apache2-utils
```

and ran

```
a2enmod cgi alias env
```

I want to use `ScriptAlias` command. However I get the message Command is missing.

I find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28422902/apache-invalid-command-scriptalias)
where suggestion was made that I should use

```
a2enmod mod_alias
```

When I use it I get the message

```
Module mod_alias does not exist
```

Do you have any suggestions how to solve this ?

I try to configure git with [these instructions](https://git-scm.com/book/be/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Smart-HTTP).

Comment: Shouldn't necessarily need to do this but did restart apache afterwards?

Answer (score 5):

Under debian, you can load the mod_alias module using:

```
$ sudo a2enmod alias
```

You should see two symbolic links `alias.conf` and `alias.load` in the folder `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled`.

After running this command, make sure that your current httpd configuration is correct using the following command:

```
$ sudo apache2ctl configtest
```

If no error message appears, restart the httpd server in order to activate this configuration change:

```
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```